# probability question involving set theory

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

How to show $P(B\ \cap\ A^c)=P(B)-P(A)$, where $A \in \mathcal{F}, B \in \mathcal{F}$ and $A \subseteq B$, for some $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$?

Is it enough to say: $P(B\ \cap\ A^c)=P((B^c)^c\ \cap\ A^c)=P((B^c\ \cup\ A)^c)=P(B)-P(A)$ using De Morgan's law. To me that's saying the same thing just reframed. Saw another attempted answer where the proof of monotonicity was used.

Answer (score 1):

Write $A^c\cup B$ as a disjoint union:

$$A^c\cup B=(A^c\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A^c)\cup (A^c\cap B)=(A^c\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A)\cup (A^c\cap B).$$

Since $A\subseteq B$, so $A^c\cup B=\Omega$ and therefore $$\Omega=B^c\cup A\cup (A^c\cap B)$$ from which the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write instead $B=A\sqcup (B\cup A^c)$, and recall the basic axioms of a probability measure.

Comment: Do you mean $B=A\ \cup\ (B\ \cup A^c)$?

Comment: Yes, the square cup is supposed to mean that the union is disjoint.